# Error in summary.factor(X[[i]], ...) : object 'AGE_YEARS' not found

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to analyse some data but whenever I run the code I come up with the message 
`Error in summary.factor(X[[i]], ...) : object 'AGE_YEARS' not found`

the code I used is as follows:

```
data$AGE_YEARS <- as.numeric(data$AGE_YEARS)
gen_age_desc <- data %>%
  summary(mean = mean(AGE_YEARS, na.rm=True),
            sd = sd(AGE_YEARS),
            min = min(AGE_YEARS),
            max = max(AGE_YEARS)
            ) %>%
  modify(round,2)
```

According to my tutor there are 2 problems with the code however I cannot figure it out. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two issues  are 1) `na.rm = True`. it would be `na.rm = TRUE`, 2) `summary` should be `summarise`.  `summary` is a `base R` function

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
 summarise(mean = mean(AGE_YEARS, na.rm=TRUE),
        sd = sd(AGE_YEARS),
        min = min(AGE_YEARS),
        max = max(AGE_YEARS)
        ) %>%
    modify(round,2)
```

Comment: oh yes! I'll do that now :)